# Can we merge ruby-on-rails-3 and ruby-on-rails3?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

These tags seem to indicate the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

They have since been merged: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby-on-rails-3/synonyms